# Validity of checking exact value of preset double

Tags: c++

I sometimes do the following in my code when I am being lazy:

```
double d = 0;
 ...
if( condition1 ) d = 1.0;

...
if (d == 0) { //not sure if this is valid
}
```

can I always count on the fact that if I set a `double` to be `0` I can later check in the code for it with `d == 0` reliably?

I understand that if I do computations on `d` in the above code, I can never expect `d` to be exactly `0` but if I set it, I would think I can. All my testing so far on various systems seem to indicate that this is legitimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for most cases (i.e. excluding NaN): After the assignment `a = b;` the condition `a == b` is true. So as long as you're only assigning and comparing to the thing you assign from, this should be reliable, even for floating-point types.

Comment: Thanks. Was always not sure of this.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid it. While the comparison would almost certainly work in the example you gave, it could fall apart unexpectedly when you use values that cannot be exactly expressed using a floating point variable. Where a value cannot be exactly expressed in a floating point variable some precision may be lost when copying from the coprocessor to memory, which would not match a value that stayed in the coprocessor the whole time.

My preference would be to add a range e.g. if (fabs(d)<0.0001) or keep the information in a boolean.

**Edit:** From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding): "For example, the decimal number 0.1 is not representable in binary floating-point of any finite precision; the exact binary representation would have a "1100" sequence continuing endlessly:"

So if you had if (d==0.1) that has the potential to create a big mess - are you sure you will **never** have to change the code in this way?