# When a double with an integer value is cast to an integer, is it guaranteed to do it 'properly'?

Tags: c, floating-point, lua

When a double has an 'exact' integer value, like so:

```
double x = 1.0;
double y = 123123;
double z = -4.000000;
```

Is it guaranteed that it will round properly to 1, 123123, and -4 when cast to an integer type via (int)x, (int)y, (int)z? (And not truncate to 0, 123122 or -5 b/c of floating point weirdness). I ask b/c according to [this page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FloatingPoint) (which is about fp's in lua, a language that only has doubles as its numeric type by default), talks about how integer operations with doubles are exact according to IEEE 754, but I'm not sure if, when calling C-functions with integer type parameters, I need to worry about rounding doubles manually, or it is taken care of when the doubles have exact integer values.

Comment: You should clarify a few items here a) by double do you mean 8 bytes or 4 bytes and b) by correct do you mean round goes towards zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154687/validity-of-checking-exact-value-of-preset-double

Comment: There is no "rounding" taking place.  The cast performs truncation.

Comment: @JaredPar: I had 8-byte floating points in mind, but I guess it doesn't matter. By rounding, I meant rounding to the nearest integer.

Comment: It's fine, as long as your compiler's int type is not more than 32-bits and you assigned the double from a literal value (not computed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, *if* the integer value fits in an `int`.

A `double` could represent integer values that are out of range for your `int` type.  For example, `123123.0` cannot be converted to an `int` if your `int` type has only 16 bits.

It's also not guaranteed that a `double` can represent every value a particular type can represent.  IEEE 754 uses something like 52 or 53 bits for the mantissa.  If your `long` has 64 bits, then converting a very large `long` to `double` and back might not give the same value.

Comment: The standard does give that guarantee for values whose integral part can be represented in the target type in 6.3.1.4: "When a ﬁnite value of real ﬂoating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undeﬁned."

Comment: @DanielFischer:  Thanks for the reference.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel Fischer stated, if the value of the integer part of the double (in your case, the double exactly) is representable in the type you are converting to, the result is exact. If the value is out of range of the destination type, the behavior is undefined. “Undefined” means the standard allows any behavior: You might get the closest representable number, you might get zero, you might get an exception, or the computer might explode. (Note: While the C standard permits your computer to explode, or even to destroy the universe, it is likely the manufacturer’s specifications impose a stricter limit on the behavior.)

Comment: In spite of my levity about undefined behavior, I want to point out it has serious consequences. Suppose you assume some results will be wrong because they are out of bounds, but you will detect and discard them after conversion. An unintended consequence of the compiler’s optimizer is that, if it can prove your code gets undefined behavior, it can optimize away your code and anything that calls it, replacing it with deliberate program exits or any other code.

Comment: ... if the warding invoked by those manufacturer's specifications is insufficient: *here be [nasal daemons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)* ....!

Answer (score 1):

It will do it correctly, if it *really* is true integer, which you might be assured of in some contexts.  But if the value is the result of previous floating point calculations, you could not easily know that.

Why not explicitly calculate the value with the [floor()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor/) function, as in `long value = floor(x + 0.5)`.  Or, even better, use the [modf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/modf/) function to inspect for an integer value.

Comment: If you know the value is an integer then there is no advantage in using the floor() function vs. a cast (except when the language has no integer type, e.g. Lua, JS.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will hold the exact value you give it because you input it in code. Sometimes in calculations it would yield 0.99999999999 for example but that is due to the error in calculating with doubles not its storing capacity